# rails 4 locale switcher not working on heroku

Tags: heroku, locale, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I have a bilingual **rails 4** application deployed in **Heroku** - russian & english.
Everything worked until one day the locale switcher broke for no reason. It's working completely fine on **development** and **production** version - when I point to language link it shows the normal link with **'localhost:3000/en'** or **'localhost:3000/ru'** param. But in Heroku it shows **'abarskaya.com/%7B:locale=>'** instead of **'abarskaya.com/ru'** or **'abarskaya.com/en'**. This is really strange as I didn't change anything.
Here's my application controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  before_filter :set_locale

  protected
  def set_locale
    I18n.locale = params[:locale] || session[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
  end

  # ensure locale persists
  def default_url_options(options={})
    logger.debug "default_url_options is passed options: #{options.inspect}\n"
    { locale: I18n.locale }
  end
end
```

And my route.rb file is:

```
scope "(:locale)", locale: /ru|en/ do
  get 'about' => 'home#about', :as => 'about'
  get 'services' => 'home#services', :as => 'services'
  get 'contacts' => 'home#contacts', :as => 'contacts'
end

root :to => 'home#index'
get '/:locale' => 'home#index'
```

Here's the switcher itself in **shared/_header.html.erb** partial (I'm using **rails_bootstrap_navbar** gem)

```
<li class="dropdown visible-desktop">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><%= image_tag(:en == locale ? 'us-flag.png' : 'ru-flag.png') %> <b class="caret"></b></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li class="nav-header"><%= t(:language) %></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <%= menu_item 'English', locale: 'en' %>
    <%= menu_item 'Русский', locale: 'ru' %>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Any help will be appreciated. Anyway I'm pretty sure that I have some dumb mistake somewhere. ;)

Comment: Hi I don't know what the issue is but I wanted to thank you for posting this setup. It got me started with a lang switcher. Thanks a lot!

Actually I have an issue with the root path myself it always returns e.g. domain.com/?locale=en or domain.com/?locale=de

I believe the issue here is the route of get '/:locale' => 'home#index' it should be before the root :to